# Understanding InheritableThreadLocal in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local, inheritable-thread-local

I wanted a `ParentThread` to have `threadId` set to the value (say `p1`) passed to its constructor. Then all its child have `threadId` set to `p1.c1`, `p1.c2` and so on. I wrote following code:

```
public class InheritableThreadLocalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        ParentThread pt = new ParentThread("p1"); 
        pt.start(); 
    } 
}

class ParentThread extends Thread { 
    static int childCount = 0;

    public static InheritableThreadLocal threadId = new InheritableThreadLocal() {
        public Object childValue(Object parentValue) 
        { 
            return parentValue.toString() + ".c" + (++childCount) ;  //this is line 18 where NullPointerException is occuring
        }
    }; 

    public ParentThread(String pThreadId) {
        threadId.set(pThreadId);
    }

    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Thread id:" + threadId.get());

        ChildThread childThread1 = new ChildThread(); 
        childThread1.start(); 

        ChildThread childThread2 = new ChildThread(); 
        childThread2.start();
    } 
} 
class ChildThread extends Thread { 

    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Child Thread Value :" + ParentThread.threadId.get()); 
    } 
}
```

It prints:

```
Thread id:null
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mahesha999.examples.java.multithreading.ParentThread$1.childValue(InheritableThreadLocalDemo.java:18)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.createInheritedMap(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mahesha999.examples.java.multithreading.ChildThread.<init>(InheritableThreadLocalDemo.java:37)
    at com.mahesha999.examples.java.multithreading.ParentThread.run(InheritableThreadLocalDemo.java:30)
```

I debuged in eclipse and found that inside constructor `threadId` is correctly set to `p1`, but inside `ParentThread.run()`, its read as `null`. Also, inside `childValue` , `.toString()` is called on `null`, throwing `NullPointerException`.

**Q1.** *Why the value set in constructor is not visible inside `run()` and `childValue()`?

Also I want this `ParentClass` reusable, that is I should be able to have series like

- `p2.c1`, `p2.c2` and so on
- `p3.c1`, `p3.c2` and so on
- and so on

I feel, for this, I should make `childCount` and `threadId` non-static. But removing `static` from both these variables gives me compile time error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field ParentThread.threadId
```

inside `ChildThread.run()` for `ParentThread.threadId.get()`. But, now I am not able to imagine how can I make these `InheritableThreadLocal` variables unique per thread per instance.

**Q2.** How should I do this?

**Q3.** Or am missing something stupid here? Is "unique per Thread per instance" is nothing but "unique per instance only" and we dont need the concept of thread-local at all in this case? Is this why all `ThreadLocal` variables should be `static` by convention?

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion is thinking a ThreadLocal is associated with a Thread object that you embed it in. It is associated with whatever the [current thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()) is when the thread local methods are called. Your have 4 threads here:

1. Main Thread
2. Parent Thread
3. Child Thread #1
4. Child Thread #2

The constructor that calls the thread local set method for the Parent Object is called within the Main Thread (#1), setting the thread local for *that* thread not the Parent Thread (#2) because it has not yet started running.

Here's a minimal working example without overriding anything in the thread class:

```
package foo;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class InheritableThreadLocalDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final AtomicInteger childCount = new AtomicInteger();

        final InheritableThreadLocal<String> local = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>() {
            public String childValue(String parentValue) {
                return parentValue.toString() + ".c" + (childCount.incrementAndGet());
            }
        };

        final Runnable child = () -> {
            System.out.println("Child Thread Value: " + local.get());
        };

        final Runnable parent = () -> {
            // The thread local value is associated with the thread that is running this block of
            // code.
            local.set("p1");
            System.out.println("Thread id:" + local.get());

            Thread c1 = new Thread(child);
            c1.start();

            Thread c2 = new Thread(child);
            c2.start();
        };

        final Thread parentThread = new Thread(parent);
        parentThread.run();
    }
}
```

In this example there is a single thread local instance that is being shared between the child and parent Runnables. Under the hood these lambdas store the locally referenced threadLocal as a member field which you can inspect during debugging. But the scoping aspect to this is separate.

Think of a thread-local like a key into per-thread map structure.

```
class Thread {
    Map<ThreadLocal, Object> threadLocals;
    // getter
    Map<ThreadLocal, Object> getThreadLocals() { return threadLocals; }
}
```

Each different ThreadLocal instance is itself a key into this structure. The *current thread* is defined as the result of the call Thread.currentThread(). So, think of every time you call threadLocalInstance.get() it is doing this:

```
Object thisThreadValue = Thread.currentThread().getThreadLocals().get(threadLocalInstance);
```

Comment: I was also struggling to understand how to use ThreadLocal's: by making them `static` class level, by making them `non-static` instance level and then, above you gave code with local-method level !!!

Comment: `local` is local to `InheritableThreadLocalDemo.main()` meaning it wont be accessible to any other methods of `InheritableThreadLocalDemo`. I am guessing what will be its scope when inherited by `parent` and `child`, local  or instance or class level thread local? I guess they will be instance level inside `parent` and `child`, right?

Comment: Re, "...the running thread." Which thread is "the running thread" on a system where four or eight CPUs, are all actively running threads that belong to the same program? Unfortunately, a lot of OS API documentation uses the phrase "current thread" because it makes sense _when you're reading the OS source code,_ but it does _not_ make sense when you're writing application code. Any place you see "current thread" in API docs, you should just automatically read it as, "the _calling_ thread."

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the relevant sections of code.

```
class ParentThread extends Thread { 
    // ...
    public ParentThread(String pThreadId) {
        threadId.set(pThreadId);
    }
```

So `threadId` will be set for the `Thread.currentThread()` that runs the constructor. This cannot be the instance that is being constructed.

```
    public void run() 
    { 
        System.out.println("Thread id:" + threadId.get());
```

Now in presumably the new thread, `threadId` will not be initialised.

```
        ChildThread childThread1 = new ChildThread();
```

And here the `null` is dereferenced.

Generally I would avoid `ThreadLocal`, and most other things associated with global variables. `InheritableThreadLocal` I would run screaming from though it has provided entertainment.